# Angular 8 - Http post return error when is not error

Tags: angular, http

I try to make an http post request to a API.
The problem is the follow: the API return a 200 status code, a success petition. But in my code works like in the http been an error.

My service code:

```
  getUsers(data) {
      const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        "Accept": "application/json"
      })
      };

      let input = new FormData();
      input.append('firstName', data.firstName);

      return this.http.post('http://localhost/post.php', input, httpOptions);
    }
```

My component code:

```
callApi(data) {
    this.userService.getUsers(data)
    .subscribe(
      (data) => { // Success
        console.log(data)
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error("Error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
      }
    );
  }
```

The browser return:
[image: the follow]

The http post result [image: is the follow]

What can be the problem?

Comment: can you post what you see inside JSON.stringify(error);

Comment: @Sajeetharan i update the post. The screenshot is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3UPH.png

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify that the data to be returned is not JSON using the [`responseType`](https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-non-json-data).In your code, you can use a responseType string value of text, like this:

```
return this.http.post(
    'http://localhost/post.php',
    {responseType: 'text'})
```

Comment: I try that but it returns a CORS error. I need to check that

Comment: when calling from another domain you might need to enble cors on the backend beacuse that can actually throw an error or any other backenc error